Implicit uses of Countable or Dependent Choice
What are instances of implicit reliance on countable or dependent choice in classic books?  Two examples are

Introduction to Commutative Algebra by M.F. Atiyah and I.G. MacDonald

where it is claimed, in remark 1 after corollary 1.5, that a certain argument does not require the Axiom of Choice but in fact the argument does use Dependent Choice, as pointed out in this question (now deleted), and on page 42 in

P. Halmos, Measure Theory, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 18, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1974 (reprint of the edition published by Van Nostrand, New York, 1950)

where countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure is proved without mentioning Countable Choice (which is needed).
Note that I am not interested in opinions as to whether the authors were really aware of the implicit use and did not mention it, or were unaware of it; only the factual instances of such arguments not mentioning reliance on countable or dependent choice explicitly.

Probably this should be restricted to books that elsewhere in the book make a big deal about certain results requiring the Axiom of Choice (e.g. existence of non-measurable sets in real analysis texts).

I agree with @DaveLRenfro that a severe restriction on the books is appropriate. The axiom of choice is part of  the standard foundational framework ZFC used throughout most of mathematics. So there is no general obligation to point it out whenever one uses it.  In  my opinion, mentioning choice whenever it's used is similar to mentioning the axioms of power set or infinity whenever they're used.

@DaveLRenfro Even with that restriction, most textbooks in analysis, particularly functional analysis, would qualify. It will usually be mentioned that Hahn-Banach requires some form of choice, but much basic functional analysis uses DC implicitly and this is rarely pointed out. See Martin Väth's answer to What can be preserved in mathematics if all constructions are carried out in ZF? for more information.

@DaveLRenfro, in both examples I mentioned (Atiyah-MacDonald and Halmos), full AC is explicitly mentioned in the book.  I haven't checked Rudin (see Hart's answer) yet.

@AndreasBlass, unlike the Axiom of Power Set, the Axiom of Choice is explicitly mentioned in both books I mentioned; see above.

@MikhailKatz I think Andreas Blass's point is that even if the axiom of choice is mentioned somewhere in the book, it will be rare to call attention to every use. For example, I strongly suspect that if you go to the library and look through a dozen books about Lebesgue measure, very few if any will mention that the countable additivity requires countable choice.

@Timothy Chow: I agree, and I was thinking of saying more but decided not to (hoping that "make a big deal" would suffice). To me the issue is not qualifying with something like "arbitrary choice" or "uncountable choice" in these discussions, and maybe or maybe not (depending on author and audience) mentioning strange things like the the possibility of the reals being a countable union of countable sets and other anomalies if no form of AC is permitted. (continued)

(From a 24 May 2007 sci.math post, as a reply to Martin Väth no less) This is a point I've been making for many years in sci.math. If it's uncountable choice that someone is concerned about, then they should say so.

@TimothyChow, I am specifically looking for classic books. For example, the book Bühler, Theo; Salamon, Dietmar A. Functional analysis. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 191. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2018 does mention it.

@MikhailKatz What makes a book classic? This is a serious question. My first thought was the date of publication, but 2018 is much more recent than the cutoff I would have proposed. Maybe it's not date of publication, but fame? I don't think I've heard of Bühler and Salamon's book before. That may just reflect my ignorance, but the point is that if you're serious about enforcing the "classic book" constraint then I think you need to be more precise about what that term means.

I didn't say that Buhler and Salamon is necessarily a "classic".  I only pointed out that they are more careful about uses of AC than most textbooks.  Being a "classic" is certainly determined by widespread use, not necessarily by the publication date.  Atiyah-MacDonald is certainly a classic in this sense, as is Rudin.  Note that Rudin does not mention AC at all, however.  @TimothyChow

@MikhailKatz Okay. Perhaps Royden's book, Real Analysis, counts as a classic? I have the third edition in front of me. In Chapter 3, Section 2 ("Outer Measure"), the proof of Proposition 2 says, "the collection ... is countable, being the union of a countable number of countable collections." The axiom of choice is not mentioned.

@TimothyChow, the other criterion that multiple users mentioned above is that the book should (in addition to being a classic) also mention AC explicitly elsewhere.  Does Royden do that?

@MikhailKatz Yes, in Chapter 3, Section 4 ("A Nonmeasurable Set"), Royden's proof explicitly mentions the axiom of choice.

@TimothyChow, good, you should post this as an answer.  Royden is certainly a classic.  I used to have a copy but can't find it right now.  I assume he proves the sigma-subadditivity of the outer measure without mentioning ACC, which is exactly what Halmos does, as well.  Anyway Royden is a better example than Rudin because Rudin does not seem to mention AC at all (nor does he mention the powerset axiom, etc., as per Blass's comment above).

Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (and most every book on Mathematical Analysis) in the proof that $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=q$ is equivalent to "$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(p_n)=q$ for every sequence $\langle p_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ such that $p_n\neq p$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=p$" (and hence that $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-continuity is equivalent to sequential continuity).
Given the $\varepsilon>0$ without a suitable $\delta$ we get "Taking $\delta_n=1/n$ ($n=1,2,3,\ldots$), we thus find a sequence satisfying $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=p$ for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(p_n)=q$ is false."
Rudin uses the same argument to show that a limit point of a set is the limit of a sequence in that set.
Addendum To answer Gro-Tsen's question in the comment below: part of that magic can be found in Exercise 3.2.(b) of Engelking's General Topology, the original source is Note de tératopologie. II (Rev. Sci. 77, 180-181 (1939)) by Bourbaki and Dieudonné. The formulation that Herrlich uses is: if $D$ is dense in $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a map, where $Y$ is regular then $f$ is continuous iff it is continuous on the subspace $D\cup\{x\}$ for every $x\in X$.
The second part of the magic is that Herrlich only works in $\mathbb{R}$. First you fix an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ and show, for every $x$ that if $f\mathbin\upharpoonright(\mathbb{Q}\cup\{x\})$ is sequentially continuous at $x$ then it is is $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-continuous at $x$ by letting $p_n$ be the first rational after $p_{n-1}$ with $|x-p_n|<1/n$ and $|f(x)-f(p_n)|\ge\varepsilon$.
That argument shows that the equivalence holds for separable metrizable domains.
For larger metrizable spaces you'll need a well-orderable dense set to make this argument go through.

It's worth noting in relation to this answer that while the equivalence between sequential and ε,δ-continuity at a point requires some form of Choice, the equivalence between sequential and ε,δ-continuity everywhere is a theorem of ZF: see Herrlich, Axiom of Choice (2006), theorem 3.15. I'm still very confused as to what magic makes this possible.

@Gro-Tsen: The rational numbers are well-orderable.

KP Hart, did you happen to notice whether Rudin mentions the Axiom of Choice explicitly elsewhere in his book?

I see that Rudin proves countable subadditivity of the outer measure in theorem 11.8 on page 304, without mentioning the Axiom of Choice (of course countable choice is needed here).  On the other hand, Rudin does not seem to mention AC at all in the book.  I am looking at the third edition apparently from 1976.

@MikhailKatz I looked but could not find anything. Rudin certainly knew his Set Theory, but I think he was completely comfortable with the Axiom of Choice. In the proof of the Hahn-Banach theorem in Functional Analysis he does the one-step extension and then says that "The second part of the proof can be done by whatever one's favorite method of transfinite induction is; well-ordering, Zorn's lemma, or Hausdorff's maximality theorem:" He uses the last one. In the appendix he indicates where that theorem is also used in the book: Krein-Milman and the maximal-ideal theorem in rings.

Wow, there was wild debate about this at the time, and a lot was written since then about the debate. As I recall Borel didn't like AC.

@MikhailKatz It seems that for many analysts the Axiom of Choice was unproblematic, see for example Banach's proof of the Hahn-Banach theorem in Studia Mathematica, 1 (1929), 211-216. The one-step extension is proven as Theorem 1, the full theorem is Theorem 2: On prouve ce théorème par induction transfinie en appliquant succesivement le théorème 1 aux éléments de l'ensemble $E-G$ (supposé bien ordonné).

The axiom of dependent choice is sometimes implicitly used in the context of chain conditions in algebra.
If $(X,\le)$ is a partially ordered set, then we say that it is well-founded if every nonempty subset of $X$ has a minimal element with respect to $\le$. (This is different to asking that $(X,\le)$ is well-ordered. A partially ordered set is well-ordered if and only if it is well-founded and totally ordered.)
Theorem (ZF+dependent choice). Let $(X,\le)$ be a partially ordered set. Then, $(X,\le)$ is well-founded if and only if there does not exist a descending chain $a_0>a_1>a_2>\cdots$ of elements of $X$.
Proof. $(\Rightarrow)$ This direction doesn't require any choice whatsoever. Suppose a descending chain $a_0>a_1>a_2>\cdots$ does exist. Then, $\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ does not have a minimal element.
$(\Leftarrow)$ If $(X,\le)$ is not well-founded, then there exists a nonempty subset $E$ of $X$ which does not have a minimal element. That is, for all $x\in E$ there is a $y\in E$ such that $x>y$. By applying the axiom of dependent choice to the relation $>$, we see that a descending chain of elements of $E$ exists. QED.
Taking $X$ to be the set of ideals of a commutative ring $R$, and $\le$ to be the relation $\supseteq$, we derive the following corollary.
Corollary. The following definitions of a Noetherian commutative ring $R$ are equivalent in the presence of dependent choice: (i) any nonempty collection $\mathcal A$ of ideals of $R$ has a maximal element with respect to $\subseteq$; (ii) there does not exist a chain $\mathfrak a_1\subsetneq\mathfrak a_2\subsetneq\mathfrak a_3\subsetneq \cdots$ of ideals of $R$.
(Note that the chain $\mathfrak a_1\subsetneq\mathfrak a_2\subsetneq\mathfrak a_3\subsetneq\cdots$ is descending from the point of view of the relation $\supseteq$, even though it is usually called ascending in commutative algebra.)
Actually, both the theorem above and the corollary also appear in Atiyah-Macdonald (Chapter 6 on Chain Conditions), giving us another place where dependent choice is implicitly used in that book.

I was so shocked by the assertion that Joel David Hamkins considered (ii) to be better than (i) that I clicked the link to his comment and found that he didn't actually say that. What he says is better than (i) is the $\in$-induction scheme, which is very different from (ii) and in fact implies (i) without any use of choice. For the record, $\in$-induction says that, for every formula $\phi(x)$, possibly with parameters, $\forall x,[(\forall y\in x,\phi(x))\to\phi(x)]$ implies $\forall x,\phi(x)$.

@AndreasBlass: Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer. Apologies to Joel for misrepresenting what he said.

Oops! The "for the record" part of my previous comment contained a typo: $\forall y\in x,\phi(x)$ should have been $\forall y\in x,\phi(y)$.

Halmos is not alone in proving the countable additivity of Lebesgue measure without explicitly mentioning (countable) choice. I have the third edition of H. L. Royden's Real Analysis in front of me. In Chapter 3, Section 2 ("Outer Measure"), the proof of Proposition 2 says, "the collection … is countable, being the union of a countable number of countable collections." The axiom of choice is not mentioned. (Later on in the same chapter, when proving the existence of a non-measurable set, Royden does mention the axiom of choice explicitly.)
While I haven't checked, I expect that it is the norm rather than the exception for textbooks to mention the axiom of choice explicitly when proving the existence of a non-measurable set, but to omit mentioning countable choice explicitly, even though the latter is essential to the standard development of measure theory.
